# How can I knock out a person instead of killing them?

Tags: hitman-absolution

Sometimes it is more convenient or beneficial to incapacitate a person rather than letting them go about their business. Sometimes that person is a civilian, which means killing them incurs a massive penalty to my score. It seems most of the available attacks are lethal, what are the way non-lethal ways to take somebody out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Sneak behind the target with your weapon holstered (<kbd>Caps lock</kbd>) and subdue (<kbd>Q</kbd>, if playing the PC version)
2. Let them spot you away from other targets and they will follow you, go to a secluded area and fake surrender (<kbd>X</kbd>), you will then have the option to knock them out with their own weapon(<kbd>Q</kbd>)
3. Grab them from around a corner by holding the left mouse button while they approach(holster any weapons).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the no weapon part?

Comment: Holster your weapon. If you have a gun or fiber wire out put it away.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your bare hands equipped and press the action button, you will be prompted to tap a button (X on this Xbox) in order to subdue. This is an alternative to snapping their neck. When you subdue someone, you still lose points as opposed to leaving them but if you hide the body in a bin (dumpster), you will get your points back.

Edit: You lose more points if you kill someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can take people as a human shield even if you have a weapon out, so it's a faster knock out. It does the same thing as subduing but it's faster.

Comment: Eccept that using human shield counts as getting spotted.
So it's not an option if you go for a higher score.